# Which of the following are avl trees?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

[image: diagram related to the question]

In the attached picture there are two Binary search trees. When I saw this question I thought that first tree is not balanced so it's not an avl tree and as second one is balanced it's obviously an avl tree.

But here the problem is when I saw the answer for this question it was given both (i) & (ii) are avl trees. How come (i) is an avl tree when it's clearly not balanced?

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

Yes, both trees **can** be considered AVL trees if a height of an empty tree is defined as `0`.

## Long Answer

Let's take a definition of an AVL tree from [here](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/avltree.html):

> A balanced binary search tree where the height of the two **subtrees** (children) of a node differs by at most one

Now, what is the height of a tree? It's a number of edges on the longest path from the root to a leaf.

Let's take a node in question `13` from your example `i`. Its right subtree is empty and its left subtree consists of a line of `2` nodes - `10` and `11`:

```
               ...
                13
               /
             11 (height = 1)
            /
           10 (height = 0) 
              ...
```

So, the height of the left subtree is `1` (the longest path from its root `11` to `10` is obviously `1`) and that of the right subtree can be considered `0` (please see more [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/336/112453)). Hence, the absolute difference of heights is `1`.

I believe it's obvious to you that for any other node in the tree `i`, the absolute difference of subtree heights is not larger than `1`, and so the tree is an AVL tree.

## Remark

As pointed out by @templatetypedef, however, if a height of an empty subtree is defined as `-1`, then the tree is no longer an AVL tree because a balance factor at `13` is `1 - (-1) = 2`. So, it all depends on how the height of an empty tree is defined. To make matters worse, the height of an empty tree is not defined - please check [here](https://translate.yandex.ru/translate?lang=en-ru&url=https%3A%2F%2Fxlinux.nist.gov%2Fdads%2FHTML%2Fheight.html&view=c).

Comment: Are you sure about this? The right subtree of the root isn’t balanced.

Comment: @templatetypedef Well, if you consider a height of an empty subtree negative, then, obviously, the tree is no longer an AVL tree.

Comment: I would imagine we should treat an empty tree as having a lower height than a node with a single tree in it. It would be unusual if those were considered to be equally tall.

Comment: @templatetypedef `-1` is one possibility. However, since there's no strict definition for a height of an empty tree (a distance shouldn't be negative, right?), it can also be `0`. That's why I edited my answer to reflect that - *both trees can be considered AVL trees if a height of an empty tree is defined as 0.* Anyways, the question from the test is not good since there are several answers depending on the interpretation of the height of an empty tree.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that tree 2 is not an AVL tree. The right subtree of the root - the one rooted at 13 - is not balanced. Specifically, its left subtree (the one rooted at 11) has height 1, and its (missing) right subtree has height -1 for a height imbalance of 2.

What’s your source on this problem? Perhaps it’s a typo, or perhaps the tree wasn’t the one that was intended?

Comment: https://www.sanfoundry.com/data-structure-questions-answers-avl-tree/                 Question no. 3

Comment: @SaiNaveen Thanks. My impression is that that site isn’t particularly high-quality, and you may want to consider finding a different resource on AVL trees.